# Standard ICA Encryption Levels (XenDesktop)

Tags: security, encryption, citrix

Trying to determine if there is a default ICA posture for encryption, out of the box so to speak.

With XenDesktop in mind, I have always thought that the encryption level is defined at the application layer and would select "Secure ICA" at a pool to enable. When not enabled it would just use standard ICA connectivity and what ever security layer it may bring along with it. I heard among peers and some vauge reference to a very basic default encryption of ICA but have not been able to find any real evidence of this.

Below is a statement from Citrix eDocs, to me, it indicates that there is by default NO encryptin at all.

> Configure the Citrix User policy **SecureICA minimum encryption
>   level** setting with one of the following options:
>
> - Basic. Encrypts the client connection using a non-RC5 algorithm. It    protects the data stream from being read directly, but it can be
>     decrypted.
> - RC5 (128 bit) logon only. Encrypts the logon data with RC5 128-bit    encryption and the client connection using Basic encryption.
> - RC5 (40 bit). Encrypts the client connection with RC5 40-bit    encryption.
> - RC5 (56 bit). Encrypts the client connection with RC5 56-bit    encryption.
> - RC5 (128 bit). Encrypts the client connection with RC5 128-bit    encryption.

Is anyone able to confirm one way or the other and have any reference point?

Thanks,

jezr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work out a way to do this.

For anyone else wanting empirical evidence of a level of encryption for ICA, I was able to see the encryption level set as basic by using the "Connection Centre" of the Receiver and selecting properties on the session.